# How can I click on the text ? I have only class in this in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, click

**HTML**

```
<div class="login pull-left ml-22" onclick="ShowLoginPopup();">Sign in</div>
```

**Selenium-Java**

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='sign in']")).click();
```

How do I open this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong.

You are using

```
//div[text()='sign in']
```

but it should be

```
//div[text()='Sign in']
```

Note that character in **xpath** are **case sensitive**.

The HTML is a part of Angular website, Please induce explicit waits

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Sign in']"))).click();
```